# GeoServer SLD Polygon fill value from attribute value

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a shapefile that includes a color HEX value in the hex_col column in the attribute table.

| index | count | bin | hex_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86bc1b29fffffff | 1 | Bin 1 | #fee5d9 |
| 86bc51407ffffff | 2 | Bin 1 | #fee5d9 |
| 86bcc2427ffffff | 37 | Bin 3 | #fb6a4a |
| 86bcc242fffffff | 1 | Bin 1 | #fee5d9 |
| 86bcc2437ffffff | 36 | Bin 3 | #fb6a4a |
| 86bcc244fffffff | 82 | Bin 5 | #a50f15 |
| 86bcc245fffffff | 26 | Bin 2 | #fcae91 |
| 86bcc2467ffffff | 23 | Bin 2 | #fcae91 |

Is it possible to dynamically style the layer using the value from the "hex_col" column to fill the individual polygons?

Answer (score 0):

I have a shapefile with the text column `hexcolor`:

[image]

Use `PropertyName` to extract the value from the column:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>polyhex</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A polygon style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Color by attribute</Title>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">
                <ogc:PropertyName>hexcolor</ogc:PropertyName>
              </CssParameter>              
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>

        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

[image]